# Azure blob refuses to upload a document

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

Caused by: com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: If you are using a StorageSharedKeyCredential, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate method call.
If you are using a SAS token, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate generateSas method call.
Please remember to disable 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign' before going to production as this string can potentially contain PII.
Status code 403, "`AuthorizationFailure`This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

I have tried uploading a document to azure blob.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. There could be many reasons why the upload is not working.

Comment: Found the Solution, my access to the blob storage got restricted. Sorry for the incomplete question, will do it from next time @GauravMantri thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted too. It helps other users who might have a similar issue to keep things organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding my client IP Address in Firewalls and Virtual Networks.
If you are facing a similar problem you might not have access for reading or writing in the Azure blob.
All you need to do is open the Azure Resource group -> Storage account -> In the Security + networking section you have an option called Networking -> In the Firewall section you can see an option called **Add your client IP address**, you can check that check box and save your changes.
That's it you'll get access to read or write the blob storage after that.